# Object as JSON with a column as key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a Rate object with columns date, rate and iso_code.
I would like an output like this:

```
{
EUR: {
  date: "2015-04-23",
  rate: 1.0772,
  btc_rate: 249.824
 },
....
}
```

But if I do it like this render json:

```
Rate.all.map { |r| {r.iso_code => {date: r.date, rate: r.rate, btc_rate: r.btc_rate}} }
```

All I have is:

```
[
  {
   EUR: {
    date: "2015-04-23",
   rate: 1,
   btc_rate: 231.92
   }
 },
...
]
```

Every objects are in a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Hash[Rate.all.map{|r| [r.iso_code, {date: r.date, rate: r.rate, btc_rate: r.btc_rate}]}]
```

This works in two parts:

1. `Rate.all.map` creates an array of 2 element arrays. In each of the little arrays, we want the first element to be the key and the second element to be the value in the resulting hash.
2. `Hash[......]` turns the array from the previous step into the hash that we want.

By the way, I just learned that in ruby 2.0 you can use `array.to_h` here as a nicer-looking alternative to `Hash[array]`.

Or you can try something more "imperative style":

```
h = {}
Rate.all.each do |r|
  h[r.iso_code] = {date: r.date, rate: r.rate, btc_rate: r.btc_rate}
end
```

Or you can simplify (or complicate, depending on your viewpoint) the above approach by using `#inject`:

```
Rate.all.inject({}) do |h, r|
  h[r.iso_code] = {date: r.date, rate: r.rate, btc_rate: r.btc_rate}
  h
end
```

(By the way, in all of this, I'm assuming each rate has a different iso_code. If any rates share an iso_code, only the last one will appear in the resulting hash.)

I would speculate that the first approach would be a little less efficient than the other two in the sense that it allocates all of those arrays which later will have to be garbage collected.